# remove a element in priority_queue minheap

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am trying to implement remove function to the priority_queue STL but for minheap implementation it throws an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdc++/bits>

using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class custom_priority_queue : public priority_queue<T, vector<T>>
{
  public:

      bool remove(const T& value) {
        auto it = find(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), value);
        if (it != this->c.end()) {
            this->c.erase(it);
            make_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
            return true;
       }
       else {
        return false;
       }
 }
};

void findmedian(int arr[], int n, int k)
{
    custom_priority_queue<int> maxheap;
```

This works fine but if i try to create min heap like below

```
    custom_priority_queue<int , vector<int>, greater<int>> minheap;
```

It throws an error

```
    Too many template arguments for class template 'custom_priority_queue'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`custom_priority_queue` only has a single template argument `T`. So you can only use `custom_priority_queue<T>`, more parameters are invalid.

You need to change your declaration to:

```
template<typename T, Queue = std::vector< T >, Compare = std::less< T > >
class custom_priority_queue : public priority_queue<T, Queue, Compare >
{
```

Deriving from standard library classes is generally not a good idea, encapsulation is a better approach.